# Visual Studio Code excluded files still showing in project explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

The same configuration included in User Settings. Resetting VSCode with no effects.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Missing asterisks.

```
"**/->*<-.meta": true
```

Here is proper config from [xinyustudio](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/unity3d-using-visual-studio-code-and-hide-meta-and-other-unwanted-files/):

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
    "**/*.meta": true,
    "Temp": true,
    "Library": true,
    "ProjectSettings": true,
    "obj": true,
    ".vs": true,
    ".vscode": true,
    "Assembly-C*.*": true,
    "*.csproj":true,
    "*.orig":true,
    "*.user":true,
    "*.userprefs":true
    }
}
```